# Programmatically having ivy fetch sources

Tags: ivy

We have a custom build tool which is dependent on the ivy functionality to resolve dependencies.  The configuration of the dependencies is not an ivy.xml file, but a custom configuration that allows for.. well, irrelevant.  The key is that we're using ivy programmatically.

Given a dependency (group id, artifact id, version), we create a ModuleRevisionId:

```
ModuleRevisionId id = ModuleRevisionId.newInstance(orgName, moduleName, revisionName);
```

followed by a ModuleDescriptor. This is, I'm guessing, where I'm not convincing enough to inform ivy that I want both the target library jar file as well as the sources.  I'm just not sure what a DependencyConfiguration is vs. just a 'configuration' when creating a ModuleDescriptor.

```
DefaultModuleDescriptor md 
  = new DefaultModuleDescriptor(
       ModuleRevisionId.parse("org#standalone;working"),
       "integration",
       new java.util.Date());
DefaultDependencyDescriptor mainDep 
  = new DefaultDependencyDescriptor(id, /* force = */ true);
mainDep.addDependencyConfiguration("compile", "compile");
mainDep.addDependencyConfiguration("compile", "sources");
md.addDependency(mainDep);
md.addConfiguration(new Configuration("compile"));
md.addConfiguration(new Configuration("sources"));
```

Nor do I really understand the above vs. RetrieveOptions vs. ResolveOptions.

I need a drink.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it took a while, but I finally wrapped my head around some of this.

```
// define 'our' module
DefaultModuleDescriptor md
  = new DefaultModuleDescriptor(ModuleRevisionId.parse("org#standalone;working"),
                                /* status = */ "integration",
                                new java.util.Date());
// add a configuration to our module definition
md.addConfiguration(new Configuration("compile"));

// define a dependency our module has on the (third party, typically) dependee module
DefaultDependencyDescriptor mainDep = new DefaultDependencyDescriptor(md, dependeeModuleId, /* force = */ true, false, true);
mainDep.addDependencyConfiguration("compile", "default");
mainDep.addDependencyConfiguration("compile", "sources");

// define which configurations we want to resolve (only have 1 in this case anyway)
ResolveOptions resolveOptions = new ResolveOptions();

String[] confs = new String[] {"compile"};
resolveOptions.setConfs(confs);

resolveOptions.setTransitive(true);  // default anyway
resolveOptions.setDownload(true);    // default anyway

ResolveReport report = ivy.resolve(md, resolveOptions);
```

This pulls down both the default jar as well as the sources target.  Note that ivy has an issue where it won't transitively pull sources, though it will transitively pull 'main' jars.  So you only get the sources for immediate dependency defined here, not the sub dependencies.

One other weakness I'm trying to figure out is this assumes the target dependency has a 'sources' configuration.  I'd rather tell it to get any artifacts of type sources/source/src.  Haven't figured that one out yet.